# Change default project root - Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, git, heroku

Heroku wants a git repository in an `application root` directory with a Procfile. What is common best practice for creating an outer directory? Ideally, this outer directory is the root of my git repo, and it contains documentation and high level deployment documentation, in addition to the `application root`. Obviously - if this would mean my git repo and `application root` are in different places.

How do I fix this? Do I have two different git repos? Do I make a submodule? Is there a way to just tell Heroku *"Hey - this isn't the application root, that directory is though!"*

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The standard structure (at least for Rails apps) is to have a root folder (which is also the application's and repository's root) which contains the application code, documentation and the Procfile.

I've never seen an "outer" folder in any of the apps and I don't see how this could be a good idea. It would just make things more complex.

Example: https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app. In Rails apps for example, the documentation lives on the `doc/` directory, the README is in the root folder `README.md` and the Procfile is also in the root folder.

Comment: After seeing this - I feel incredibly oblivious. While I am using Django, I assume best practices are the same across the board. After checking out some open source projects, it's clear nobody uses this so called "outer directory". Maybe I misunderstood some blog posts here and there... Thanks for the tip!